# javascript - combine the object if the value of its field is the same

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Below is the current data

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
  { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },
  { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 },
  { id: 4, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
  { id: 5, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },
  { id: 6, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 }
]
```

I want to do some processing of the `data` based on `strike`, which means the object with same value in `strike` will be combined, so that it becomes something like

```
[
  { strike: 3000, callVolume: 50000, putVolume: 50000 },
  { strike: 5000, callVolume: 30000, putVolume: 10000 },
  { strike: 7000, callVolume: 20000, putVolume: 7000 },
]
```

How should I do it in javascript?

Comment: Please add what you have tried? You will get better responses.

Answer (score 1):

This is really just a 'group by' by `strike` with a computed property name based on `type`.

```js
const data = [    { id: 1, type: 'call', strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },    { id: 2, type: 'call', strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },    { id: 3, type: 'call', strike: 7000, volume: 20000 },    { id: 4, type: 'put', strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },    { id: 5, type: 'put', strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },    { id: 6, type: 'put', strike: 7000, volume: 7000 },  ];

const result = Object.values(
  data.reduce((a, { type, strike, volume }) => {
    (a[strike] ??= { strike })[`${type}Volume`] = volume;

    return a;
  }, {})
);

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

You could collect `volume` by each group.

```js
const
    data = [{ id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 }, { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 }, { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 }, { id: 4, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 }, { id: 5, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 }, { id: 6, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 }],
    result = Object.values(data.reduce((r, { type, strike, volume }) => {
        r[strike] ??= { strike, callVolume: 0, putVolume: 0 };
        r[strike][type + 'Volume'] += volume;
        return r;
    }, {}));

console.log(result);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: Just like in any of your other _"group by"_ answers?

Comment: it has a certain similarity ...

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **forEach/for loop** to init a item in **result** object. By using **Array.find** use can check the result exists or not to init a new result item.

```js
const data = [
    { id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },
    { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 },
    { id: 4, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
    { id: 5, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },
    { id: 6, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 }
]

let result = [];
data.forEach(item => {
  let result_item = result.find(e => e.strike == item.strike);
  var isNew = false;
  if (!result_item) {
    result_item = {
      strike: item.strike
    };
    isNew = true;
  }

  if (item.type == "call")
    result_item.callVolume = item.volume;
  else
    result_item.putVolume = item.volume;

  if (isNew) result.push(result_item);
});

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've tried to keep it as optimal as I could. First I create a hashmap by strike attribute for quick access and not double looping in each step.
After I got the hashmap, I ran a quick loop and extracted only those elements that had strike.

```
const data = [
  { id: 1, type: "call", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },
  { id: 4, type: "put", strike: 3000, volume: 50000 },

  { id: 2, type: "call", strike: 5000, volume: 30000 },
  { id: 5, type: "put", strike: 5000, volume: 10000 },

  { id: 6, type: "put", strike: 7000, volume: 7000 },
  { id: 3, type: "call", strike: 7000, volume: 20000 }
];

// Processing starts here
const hash = {};

data.forEach((item) => {
  let { volume, strike, type } = item;

  if (!hash[strike]) {
    hash[strike] = {
      strike: strike,
      [`${type}Volume`]: volume
    };
  } else {
    hash[strike] = {
      ...hash[strike],
      [`${type}Volume`]: volume
    };
  }
});

// Extract hash map data into array
// Filter and remove no match strikes
let result = [];

for (let key in hash) {
  let elm = hash[key];
  if (!elm.putVolume || !elm.callVolume) continue;

  result.push(elm);
}

console.log(result);
```